Getting Returned Value not an Array Buffer or Uint8 Array While Fetching Response from Chainlink Offchain Function
When I am Trying to call sendRequest function from my contract and get a response from the chainlink function through fulfillRequest function I am getting error in computation .
The Error says "Returned Value not an Array Buffer or Uint8 Array"
contract code for fulfillRequest Function:
    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId);
        }

        s_lastError = err;
        s_lastResponse = response;

        if (response.length > 0) {
            (uint256 healthScore, uint256 tokensEarned, string memory newUri) = abi.decode(response, (uint256, uint256, string));
         }

}

Function code snippet:
// Imports
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.12.1');
//I have removed the irrelevant code from this function but patientScore,tokensToProvide and uri are calculated inside this function and then returned to contract
// ABI encoding
const encoded = abiCoder.encode(
    ["uint256", "uint256", "string"],
    [patientScore, tokensToProvide, uri]
);

// return the encoded data as Uint8Array
return ethers.getBytes(encoded);
// return Functions.encodeUint256(patientScore);



Hi Varad, your codes look good. Can you also check if the data can be fetched from API successfully? One way to debug the issue is to hardcode the value in your js file and see if you can get it in your smart contract's callback function.

It is difficult to have a suggestion without seeing the code but here are some thoughts, if I may.
Firstly please use
const encoded = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
  ["uint256", "uint256", "uint8", "string"],
  [dataFeedResponse.answer, dataFeedResponse.updatedAt, decimals, description]
);

as seen here
The next logical thing is to make sure your script abides by these restrictions
Sometimes the error is hit further up compared to the end error message
Fundamental things to check are:

The response is up to 256 bytes
Place a dummy small string for uri and see if all goes well. If yes then you can guess that size of the response might have been the issue.
For chain hygiene if you are using the same uri again and again and only changing a parameter like account token etc then only this should be passed to the chain to keep response lower that 256 bytes
Next place to check is, are you making more than 5 http calls and do these calls complete in time as you have like <10secs to complete the task


Nothing's working I tried everything You said and still getting the same error
